# Wireframe modifier fails on some shapes. Why?

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

I have a wireframe modifier on a mutating shape.  I have an animation for it, and -- sometimes -- it just doesn't create a wireframe at all.  I believe it may have something to do with tiny pockets, which is whats focused on in the photos below.

**What's going on?  Why does it sometimes fail to create a wireframe?**

I've tried poking at pretty much every variable under wireframe modifier, and none have changed the outcome.

Link to file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12tXql8nquvOrzL7a2w1rZ7pwlFDd4Y_P/view?usp=sharing

Here is a frame with the wireframe modifier working(84):
[image]

Here is a frame where the modifier fails (83):
[image]

And the next frame it works again (82):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the wireframe modifier; it's the boolean that precedes it.

Booleans operate on *volumes* and, in order to work, they need to operate on manifold meshes.  If meshes are not manifold, then the booleans will *try* to guess what you want, but they really don't know.  The "fast" boolean solver also takes some shortcuts that can lead to errors in calculation.  Your meshes are not manifold and you're using the fast solver.

Let's look at the target of the boolean:

[image]

The normals are backwards and there are two non-manifold vertices.  Additionally, we're using a live weld modifier, which can create additional non-manifold geometry.  We'll delete the non-manifold vertices, fix any holes that made, apply the weld, recalculate normals, and recheck for any non-manifold geo.

Now let's look at the object with boolean modifier.  It's not manifold either, it's just a plane.  Well, two planes, after the array acts on it.  We'll extrude it and make sure we have proper facing normals.  We'll also change the boolean modifier to the "exact" solver:

[image]

Now, we see that the boolean is operating properly on frame 83, a previous problem.  However, we've created a problem, because in order to boolean, we needed to make a volume-- we have new edges.  We don't want these edges displayed.  We need to mark the vertices we want to keep, and because our geometry is dynamic, we need to do so with a modifier.

We'll duplicate our boolean-modified object, then delete the boolean and all modifiers that come after the boolean.  And we'll delete the extruded vertices we made.  This is now a simple plane, using the same array with the same animation as the input to our boolean:

[image]

We add a vertex group to the mesh.  Now we can use a series of modifiers to mark which vertices we want to keep and delete the rest:

[image]

1. I use a vertex weight edit modifier to assign all vertices, at weight 1.0, to Group.
2. I use a vertex weight proximity modifier to set the value of Group to 0 for all vertices that are further than 0.01 units from the arrayed plane.
3. I use a mask modifier to delete all vertices that have a Group value of 0.

After doing all this, I now have the 2D plane, ready for a wireframe.  We'll re-enable all the modifiers I disabled to see what I was doing, and we'll set our proximity object to wireframe and disable in renders.

[image]

Note: this is a situation where GN would probably simplify some of it, but as you're currently working with regular modifiers, I'm providing the regular modifier solution.  Any of these things can be done in GN instead.

Comment: This is amazingly in depth.  I'm having a hard time seeing the difference between the first and second photo.  Where should I be looking?

Comment: Well, that's because I guess I failed to properly copy a new screenshot and so just repasted the first one :)  Pic isn't necessary though (and would be a pain to recreate) so I'll just delete it.

Comment: Ha!  Cool, I had thought that might have been the issue, but I was never very good at where's waldo.  :p